# Ubuntu terminal window minify when entering

Tags: ubuntu

Problem happened today,I found when I tried to enter any word into terminal window in ubuntu,the terminal window minify itself,the height narrow to less than one row.At the same time,all file's thumbnails(I don't know if it's called thumbnails,I mean the icon which shows filetype) disappeared,now,all file's icons in my ubuntu are blank!

Comment: Install terminator tool. It's more better than the native terminal

Comment: Thanks,can you tell me winch sofrware I should install,I searched 'ubuntu terminal tool' on google just now,but I haven't found a good enougn answer.

Comment: you can download it [here](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/terminator/)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will try!

Answer (score 0):

I was running xfce4.12 DE on my ubuntu machine.Until yesterday,everything was running pretty smooth but today I noticed the same thing happening with my machine.Tried everything but all in vain. I have to switch into Unity DE and everything started working fine again. Weird!!